# Azure VMSS behind a load balancer SSL certs

Tags: ssl, azure, azure-networking

Trying to get my head around what SSL/TLS certs i need to create for a couple of webservers hosted in Azure.
The basic idea is :

External User -> Azure Load Balancer -> Webserver ( part of a VM Scale Set ).
The webservers will not be accessible publicly ( therefore no public IP address )

I am trying to get my head around what certificate information i need for the webservers( for HTTPS ) . Do i have a wildcard cert on all the VM's with the FQDN of the Load Balancer ( *.something.com)  since thats where technically the clients will connect to or do i have individual certs for each VM with the public FQDN of each VM even though they are not techically publicly available ( ex : server1.something.com | server2.something.com )  ?

Am i missing a more obvious solution ?

Thanks for any help you can provide.